# Motion tracking. How to find frames where marker is enabled/disabled (or/and not tracked yet)? Maybe via python?

Tags: python, motion-capture, marker

During motion tracking of several markers at once, it happens that some marker is lost at some frame for some reason. Then I spend a lot of time searching on which frame this marker got lost. Sometimes I do also reverse tracking and then it is very difficult to find exactly where the marker is not tracked.
*The main question.* **How can I find frames where the marker is not tracked?** ***How can I jump to untracked frame with hotkey.***
On the right panel there is a toggle for 'Enabled' in the marker section. But via python there is no way to find this property.
Are there any tips on how I can find untracked frames for each marker?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

On the bottom of the editor you can see the timeline where a yellow line shows where the current selected marker is tracked(active) with highlight on keyframes, where the marker was reset manually.

[image]

If it is not enough, you can always add an additional Movie Clip editor in Dopesheet mode. It can show every marker with start and end points:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Now I can specify the question. How can I jump to untracked frame with hotkey. That's why I asked to find those frames via python.